# Getting an indentation error after the print statement

Tags: python

Why am i getting an indentation error after the first print statement? if i dont write the for loop indentation error does not  occur but i need to find the largest and smallest number in the list. i tried adding a function after the print statements and then calling the function after the except but it still gives an error. 
 enter code here

```
largest = None
smallest = None
lis = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    lis.append(num)

for value in lis:  
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif smallest >num:
        smallest = num
    else:   


print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
"""
def min(num):
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif smallest >num:
        smallest = num
    else:
    """

enter code here
```

Comment: Hi, Try moving your `lis.append(num)` into the `try`, after `num = float(num)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put an else statement and keep it empty.
(you can put the "pass" keyword)

```
for value in lis:  
    if smallest is None or smallest > num:
        smallest = num
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, because you forgot to set the `else`.

Also, there are some other modifications that you need to do for your program to work:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
lis = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try:
        num = float(num)
        lis.append(num)             #<--- add this here
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
                                    #<--- remove this line

for value in lis:  
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = value      #<-- use `value` instead of `num`
        largest  = value      #<-- add this part
    elif smallest > value:    #<-- use `value` instead of `num`
        smallest = value      #<-- use `value` instead of `num`
    elif largest < value:     #<-- add this part
        largest = value       #<-- add this part
    else:
        pass                  #<-- add this part


print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```